# How can I start my python program in another computer

Tags: python, tkinter, dll

I have written a program in Python with tkinter. I have converted my program to exe, it worked well on my computer, but when I sent it to another computer that did not have Python, it did not work. What should I do, helppp!
My error is this:

```
Error loading python dll

C\users\home\appdata\local\temp\_mei30522\python311.dll.

Loading library: the specified module could not be found
```

[image: you can see picture]

Comment: Is there other error window before the posted one? Try to build the executable in console mode (i.e. remove `-w` or `--windowed`) when running `pyinstaller`, and run again to see whether there is other error shown in the console.

Comment: No I saw only this error
But good idea I will test it

Comment: Did you use pyinstaller with onefile or folder? If you compile it as a onefile .exe, all the data needed for the exe is in the exe itself. When it's onefile it should be able to run on any computer.

Comment: Yes I onefile it but I didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to Dockerize it https://www.docker.com/blog/containerized-python-development-part-1/